# Submitting the form after changing value in Angular Directive submits old value

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://jsfiddle.net/p8RNJ/3/

When I press "submit" button, `fooController` in controller is equal to 'A' so `barController` gets assigned value 'A', which is confirmed in UI:

```
bar in controller: A
```

After I press "set value" button, `fooController` is updated from directive through binding with value 'B', which is confirmed in UI:

```
foo in controller: B
```

However after I press "submit" button, `fooController` in controller still has old value of 'A' so `$scope.barController` once again gets assigned a value of 'A':

```
bar in controller: A
```

How can I ensure that on second submit `fooController` has correct value of 'B' and `barController` gets assigned a value of 'B' as well?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="directive-template.html">
    foo in directive: {{fooDirective}}<br/>
    <button ng-click="setValue()">set value</button>
</script>

<form data-ng-submit="getModel()">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <button type="submit">submit</button><br/>
        foo in controller: {{fooController}}<br/>
        bar in controller: {{barController}}<br/>
        <my-customer model="fooController"></my-customer>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.fooController = 'A';
    $scope.getModel = function() {
        $scope.barController = $scope.fooController;
    }
}])

.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fooDirective: '=model'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.setValue = function() {
                $scope.fooDirective = 'B';
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'directive-template.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: This question is hard to understand because of all the foos, bars, b's and a's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use primitive data types (number, strings, booleans) because the inheritance doesn't work both ways, it only works from parent $scope to chid $scope. If you want it to work both ways user objects or arrays (that's what the angular community actually recommends).

```
$scope.barController = "aaaa";
```

should be:

```
$scope.modelState.barController = "aaa";
```

This way if you change it from the child scope it will be updated in the parent one as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your directive change in $scope.apply

```
  $scope.apply(function(){
        $scope.setValue = function() {
            $scope.fooDirective = 'B';
        };
   }
```

Comment: I don't think $apply is necessary here since all the actions are within the "angular scope".

Comment: Only if the directive is using some "3rd party" api/library that's not part of angular's cycle. I never had a problem getting the $scope updated from a directive.

Comment: i have had faced exactly similar issues in directives which were solved by scope.apply, sorry if that is not relevant in this case. this is learning for me :)

Comment: I'm not an expert either, so there's a big chance you are right tho :)